# Getting out the r-channel from a argb-uint?

Tags: actionscript-3, rgb

i have an argb value in the parameter of a function and the function needs to get rid of the agb values and only keep the r. How would you do that? thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is done with bitwise shifting and bitwise AND.

The uint in a 32 bit integer. Each of the A,R,G,B takes up 8 of its bits(one byte).
And they appear I the same order as the name implies A,R,G,B

To get out b you just need to mask out all the other bits with a bitwise AND statement.

a=argb&255
because 255 in binary is 11111111, it only keeps the needed bits.

for g you first need to shift the bits then do the above.
g=argb>>8&255

r is same but shift 16 bits

r=argb>>16&255

and a
a=argb>>24&255

Hope that helps

Comment: Woah
I think I will have to read up on bitwise operators
Thanks

Comment: Heh, it's good to know about them. They can optimize certain things quite a bit. Plus, in my opinion they're fun ^^
Here's an example where it could speed up things quite a bit. It's sort of complicated though, but intreresting =)
http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/02/bitsets.html?page=2

Answer (score 2):

here's more information on it:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/bitwise_operators_print.html